# Strange behavior when converting String to DateTime

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, tostring, cultureinfo

Im experiencing strange behavior when converting String to DateTime and then again ToString().

`Convert.ToDateTime("16-02-2012").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` results in **02-16-2012**
`Convert.ToDateTime("16-02-2012").ToLongDateString()` results in **16. februar 2012**

As you can see the conversion is correct when using ToLongDateString() but somehow the / is converted to - when using ToString().

When I insert the first result into a Excel sheet the value is actually **'02-16-2012** (notice the ' in the beginning)

When I use a date where the first segment is lower than 12 the result contains / as expected but is reverted to dd/MM/yyyy.

I've tried using `new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK", false)` when converting ToDateTime() but with no effect (Our system is already set to da-DK - but I got desperate).

Anyone seen this behavior before?

**EDIT**

To clarify my post a little, the date format in danish is dd-mm-yyyy (which I want to format to mm/dd/yyyy) - I know that the first segment is month in a english date.

Comment: @vc74 - Clearly in the context of the question 16 is the day not the month.  Why did 6 people upvote this comment, it makes no sense, clearly in the region Marle is in they use the DD/MM/YYYY convention.

Comment: @Marle1 - You do understand that the code is behaving exactly how it should right?

Comment: @Marle1 The reason why it does not work is because the Denmark's culture uses a hyphen as date separator and to string uses / as the placeholder for date separator.

Comment: @Ramhound, true, I read the question too quickly.

Comment: Next time, please mark your question with the Excel tag so that other people know you're looking for Excel-specific information.

Comment: All right SpikeX. Thank you very much for your answer and please accept my excuse for not specifying that my project involved Excel in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export the data in the format you want, you can insert the data as DateTime and use a cell format like in the following example (assuming your dates are in column A):

```
Application Excel = new Application();

Workbook workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add(1);
Worksheet sheet = workbook.Sheets[1];
sheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now;
sheet.Cells[2, 1] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
sheet.Cells[3, 1] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
sheet.UsedRange.Columns["A:A", Type.Missing].NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; 
workbook.Sheets.Add(sheet);

// Save the workbook or make it visible
```

Comment: Your code produces: `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` FYI, the separator really doesn't matter: `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));` 
**02/09/2012**
`Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));`
**02-09-2012**

Comment: @SpikeX What is your culture (more precisely what's the value for DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.DateSeparator)?

Comment: @SpikeX Here's what your code produces on my (european) machine: Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")); 02-09-2012 Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")); 02-09-2012

Comment: Well vc 74, your answer almost solved my problem. The output value is now 02/16/2012 - But im still seeing the ' in front of my date in Excel. This is not the case if the first segment of the date is lower than 12. Still thinking the culture isn't getting all the way through...

Comment: @Marle1 How do you insert the data in Excel?

Comment: as a string: `worksheet.Cell(3, 34).Value = saleStartDate;` - Using the variable saleStartDate containing the formatted value results in **'02/16/2012** but using a static string like "02/16/2012" results in the correct interpretation in Excel: **02/16/2012**

Comment: if I output the variable saleStartDate to a .txt file the result is the correct value 02/16/2012. No ' in sight! What the...

Comment: Can you not use the date instead of the string to fill the spreadsheet and then format the cells in Excel. sheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now; works fine on my machine.

Comment: Well, you definitely got a point. But what im actually trying to achieve is a formatted string, because the receiver of the Excel demands that the cell information is a string in the giving format. Kind of silly, I know...

Comment: @Marle1 Yes but instead of converting it in C#, I suggest you do it in Excel, i.e. export the data as DateTime and then apply the following format cell in Excel: mm/dd/yyyy (no problems with / this time :))

Comment: @Marle1 You can even ask Excel to do the formatting from your C# code: sheet.Cells[1].NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";

Comment: Can I format the cell using the worksheet class in C#? Because im transferring the .xlsx file to a FTP directly after I generate it. It's a automatic process, so im not able to manually open the Excel and format cells before sending it to my client.

Comment: Yes you can, using the code I wrote in my comment sheet.Cells[1].NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; will format the first column with the format you expect so just add this line before you save the file and that should do it (replace 1 with the index of your date column)

Comment: Thank you for your extensive support vc 74. Much more simple... Keeping the correct datatype is the way to go!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
Convert.ToDateTime("16-02-2012").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

to

```
Convert.ToDateTime("16-02-2012").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

It's just a typo.

---

If that's not what you want, try this:

```
DateTime.Parse("16-02-2012", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"));
```

Then you can add whatever `.ToString(...)` you want on the end.

---

Edit 2: Your computer is outputting the date in your own culture. If you want it parsed *and* displayed correctly, you need to provide culture info for each operation.

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse("16-02-2012", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")).ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK")));
// 16-02-2012 00:00:00
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what the separator is.

Comment: I cannot change the code like you suggest, because that would result in the wrong result when I need to format the date from 16-02-2012 to 02/16/2012

Comment: Still the same incorrect result: 02-16-2012 - '02-16-2012 in Excel. I know the arrangement of values is now correct, but the formatting is still wrong and somehow the date is parsed incorrectly. Thanks though

Comment: Edited again. You need to provide culture information each time you parse *or* output otherwise .NET will use your current culture.

Comment: When I use culture information on Parse and ToString the result is the same: 02-16-2012.